# displaying escaped data [codeigniter]

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am saving the the values in db using `$this->db->escape();`

```
$this->db->set('last_name',$this->db->escape($lastname1));
```

it is adding single quotes, but I don't want to display single in views..is there any built in way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the single quotes are showing then you are probably escaping things twice. I've used `escape` without doubling up on the single quotes. If you look at http://www.codeignitor.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html, you'll see that `set` automatically escapes by default.

```
set() will also accept an optional third parameter ($escape), that will prevent data from being escaped if set to FALSE. To illustrate the difference, here is set() used both with and without the escape parameter.
```

So you don't need to call `escape` and you should be fine.

Comment: I checked the values in phpmyadmin, looks like set() is not adding single quotes. but when I use escape(), its adding single quotes

Comment: So it seams, that using the escape()-function is pointless, because the set()-function already adds the single quotes.

Comment: `escape` adds single quotes if they are necessary, otherwise it doesn't add single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which class you are using because the MySQLI Class from PHP doesn't have any 'escape()'-Function.

But the common way to escape insert-query's to your Database is using a [Prepared Statement](http://de.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

As i see from the Documentation, there is no real Prepared Statement in this Framework. But, i found this:

> $this->db->escape() This function
>   determines the data type so that it
>   can escape only string data. **It also
>   automatically adds single quotes
>   around the data so you don't have to**:

You should check the [Documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html).

Comment: I made some edits to my original answer. See if this solves your problem.

Comment: yeah..but I want to use the stored data..and when I use it ..it will be with single quotes..so I want a easy way to remove the single quotes ..-- Thanks